# Databricks spark sql to show associated strings from hashed strings

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hash, databricks

I'm using a query in databricks like this :

```
select * from thisdata where hashed_string in (sha2("mystring1", 512),sha2("mystring2", 512),sha2("mystring3", 512))
```

This works well and gives me the data I need, but is there a way to show the associated string to the hashed string?

example

```
mystring1 - 1494219340aa5fcb224f6b775782f297ba5487
mystring2 - 5430af17738573156426276f1e01fc3ff3c9e1
```

Probably not as theres a reason for it to be hashed, but just checking if there is a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have table with string and corresponding hash columns then you can perform inner join instead of using IN clause. After joining, using concat_ws function you can get the required result.

Let's say, you create a table with name `hashtable` where you have columns mystring and hashed_mystring and other table name as `maintable`.

You can use below query to join and extract the result in the required format.

```
select concat_ws('-',h.mystring, m.hashed_string)  from maintable m 
  inner join hashtable h on m.hashed_string = h.hashed_mystring
```